# どのは in「むこどのは…」is beyond my comprehension

Tags: grammar

> 「こりゃ、むすめ、むこどのはあの三人の中のどれじゃ。」

*context: It's a father asking that to her daughter as three men approach him.*

**What I understand**:

こりゃ、むすめ is "There, daughter"
あの三人の中のどれじゃ。 is "which one amongst these three persons?"

**What is not clear**:

むこどのは
= むこ(husband) + どの(which) + は(topic marker) right?

I don't understand because むこ and どの are both noun if I am not mistaken but they are connected together here, and I usually see どの as a noun or more commonly as a **pre-noun adjectival**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've parsed the sentence incorrectly. -どの here is [the honorific suffix](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%AE/), and the word is 婿殿.